# sql sever 2012 sum of dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server-2012, sum

Assume I have a table with 50 columns with name `AMT_0`,`AMT_1`,..`AMT_49`. Is there possible sum of dynamic number of column depending on Variable.

example1: `SELECT SUM(AMT_0,AMT_1,AMT_2,AMT_3) FROM TBL` where the Variable is equal to 4.

example2: `SELECT SUM(AMT_0,AMT_1,..,AMT_23) FROM TBL` where the Variable is equal to 24.

Comment: Maybe use rows, not columns?

Comment: Will it always be the column numbers in sequential order?  ie. variable =10, sum columns AMT_0 to AMT_9 ... variable = 20, sum columns AMT_0 to AMT_19, etc.?

Comment: yes, the column numbers are  in sequential order.

Comment: This is a design issue. You really should consider normalize your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to build some dynamic SQL.  Something like this should do the trick

```
DECLARE @var smallint;
SELECT @var = 15; -- change variable value to control # of columns summed

DECLARE @sql varchar(4000);
DECLARE @cntr smallint; -- incremental counter variable for WHILE loop
SELECT @sql = '';
SELECT @cntr = 1;

WHILE @cntr > 0 AND @cntr <= 50 AND @cntr <= @var
BEGIN
    IF @sql = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT SUM(AMT_0';
    END
    ELSE
        SQL @sql += ' + AMT_' + CONVERT(varchar(10), (@cntr-1));
    END

    SELECT @cntr += 1;
END

SELECT @sql += ') FROM TBL;';

EXEC (@sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ideally, you should redesign your database, so that `AMT` is normalized into rows.** Then the query is far simpler and does not require dynamic SQL.

---

The only way to do this as it stands is with dynamic SQL, you need to make sure to check all columns exists by looking them up in system tables, and quote all the column names properly:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT SUM(
' +
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), N',')
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'TBL')
      AND c.name LIKE N'AMT_%'
) + N'
)
FROM TBL
';

EXEC (@sql)
```